# How to save responses from registered users and process/filter them in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, django-forms

TLDR; Django newbie here, following [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html#practical-example) blog, I tried to create a Django app where the students can answer the questions using normal text instead of multiple choice question.

This project currently lets the teachers create 'Quiz'es, in which the owner is the teacher creating it, gives the quiz a name and chooses which subject it is (e.g. Maths, History). The quiz is a multiple choice type, with a few correct answers. Every correct answer awards 100 points, and the teacher defines which responses are the correct ones.

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every student has some chosen interests, based on which quizzes can appear in his feed.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_students')

    def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz):
        answered_questions = self.quiz_answers \
            .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz) \
            .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
        questions = quiz.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
        return questions

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Every time a student answers a quiz, the answers are saved in a model called StudentAnswer.

```
class TakenQuiz(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    score = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class StudentAnswer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_answers')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

**Now the problem is, this model saves the response of the student in ModelChoiceField form, and I want to convert it to a normal text input field form. And if I do convert just the model type, it gives me an error that the answer must be a StudentAnswer instance.**

```
class TakeQuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Answer.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        required=True,
        empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = StudentAnswer
        fields = ('answer', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question = kwargs.pop('question')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].queryset = question.answers.order_by('text')
```

*I just need to know how I can convert this app to take in normal text input, and save it to show the teacher. Then, the teacher can themselves grade it correct/incorrect. I was able to add another field to the StudentAnswer model, called comments, so that the teacher can view it, and it was being saved in the database too. But, as you can see the Many-to-Many relationship only exists between the Quiz model, Question model, and the StudentAnswer Model, and not on the newly create field 'Comments'. *

My attempt to create a field comments:

```
class StudentAnswer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_answers')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0)
```

I am fine with any kind of hints/suggestions or directions, as it has become my last resort to post it here, as the blog Author is not active anymore. I have tried manipulating several codes here and there to no good, I am basically asking for any hints for where to look at.

Summarised, **How do I connect two models, with a field which is not the primary key, so as to display it on another view.**

[Link to Git repository](https://github.com/sibtc/django-multiple-user-types-example)

Comment: Why won't anybody help me ? :(